# ASP.NET MVC Html.Action Render Post instead of GET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have blog and sometimes users catch error which i can't reproduce.

Simple PostItem.cshtml:

"Create", "Comment" - render CreateComment form

```
@Html.Action("Create", "Comment", new { @returnUrl = Request.Url, @postID = Model.ID })
<div name="#comments">
    @Html.Action("CommentsForPost", "Comment", new { postID = Model.ID })
</div>
```

CreateComment.cshtml

```
<div class="create-comment-container">
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Comment", FormMethod.Post, new { role = "form" }))
{
    @Html.Hidden("returnUrl", Request.QueryString["returnUrl"])
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.PostID)
     .........
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default pull-right">@L("Post")</button>
}
```

Then i have CommentController.cs

```
        public PartialViewResult Create(int postID, string returnUrl)
        {
            return this.PartialView("Partials/CreateComment", new Comment { PostID = postID });
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateInput(false)]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Create(Comment comment, string returnUrl)
        {
            var validator = ValidationFactory.CreateValidator<Comment>();

            var results = validator.Validate(comment);

            if (results.IsValid)
            {
                var result = await CommentManager.CreateComment(comment);
                if (result != null && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(returnUrl))
                    return Redirect(returnUrl + "#comments");
            }

            return Redirect("/");
        }

        public PartialViewResult CommentsForPost(int postID)
        {
            return PartialView("CommentsForPost", CommentManager.GetComments(postID, PaginationHelper.GetCurrentPageForName(ControllerContext.RequestContext, "commentPage"), BlogSettings.CommentPageSize));
        }
```

As you see - all actions go out with redirects!
    But some users catch error, that redirect it on the main page without save comment and i have this trace in my logs.
How it possible ?

HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_URL **/comment/create**

REQUEST_METHOD  **GET**

```
System.ArgumentException
The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'postID' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.PartialViewResult Create(Int32, System.String)' in 'geenBlog.Web.Controllers.CommentController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter. Parameter name: parameters

System.ArgumentException: The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'postID' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.PartialViewResult Create(Int32, System.String)' in 'geenBlog.Web.Controllers.CommentController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Parameter name: parameters
   at System.Web.Mvc.ActionDescriptor.ExtractParameterFromDictionary(ParameterInfo parameterInfo, IDictionary`2 parameters, MethodInfo methodInfo)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass33.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make `postID nullable` as shown :

```
 public PartialViewResult Create(int? postID, string returnUrl)
 public PartialViewResult CommentsForPost(int? postID)
```

OR if you don't want to make `postID nullable` then make sure that there is some integer value in `Model.ID` when you are passing `postID` in `@Html.Action()`

Comment: But Model.ID is always present, because we at the blog post page with post own ID. In what situation postID is not present ???

Comment: @ZOXEXIVO..like you have written in your question sometimes you catch that error it is because sometimes your Model.ID is null which causes problem because int donot accept nulls ... try my first answer set int as nullable or otherwise just check somewhere Model.ID is getting null values in some cases.

Comment: If model = null we have null reference exception in postId = Model.ID assignment. ID field declared as TKey ID { get; set; } and can't give null value!

Comment: @ZOXEXIVO..just for a test try where you are passing `Model.ID` use a condition as `@postID = (Model.ID == null ?0:Model.ID)`.

Comment: ))) Model.ID = non nullable Guid field